# Find and delete a element from a sortedset only using two of the atributes

Tags: java, iterator, set

My expression is not the best, sorry.

This is what I have:

```
public SortedSet<Tutoria> tutorias;
```

And this is the operation that I'm trying to make, which finds a Tutoria in the list tutorias, and deletes it. But the thing is, it finds it only using two of the variables, so it completely ignores the horaFin one.

Haven't been able to figure out how to find for a Tutoria that matches the horaComienzo and diaSemana but doesn't care about the other variable.

```
public void borraTutoria(LocalTime horaComienzo, DayOfWeek diaSemana) {
    }
```

This is the constructor of tutoria.

```
public TutoriaImpl(DayOfWeek diaSemana, LocalTime horaComienzo, LocalTime horaFin){
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for Tutoria class? Does it implement Comparable? Are you passing any comparator while creating the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magic here, and you may be trying to make things too hard for yourself. All you have to do is

- Iterate through the Set using its Iterator and a while or for loop
- Inside the loop, you check if the Tutorial item currently being checked has the two matching properties
- If it does, you remove it from the Set **using the iterator** (this part is key). That's it.

For example

```
Iterator<Foo> iterator = myFooSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Foo myFoo = iterator.next(); // get current item

   // check if current item's properties match two searched for 
   // properties
   if (myFoo.getBar.equals(someBar) && myFoo.getBaz.equals(someBaz)) {
       iterator.remove();
   }
}
```

Also, the equivalent code using a for loop:

```
for (Iterator<Foo> iterator = myFooSet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Foo myFoo = iterator.next(); // get current item

   // check if current item's properties match two searched for 
   // properties
    if (myFoo.getBar.equals(someBar) && myFoo.getBaz.equals(someBaz)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Of course if either of the two properties to match are primitives, then you'd use the `==` operator and not the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry I didn't mark it earlier, as I had to go do some things, thanks for the example too.